# minima calculation for 2d array in scipy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal

data = np.array([[[13, 2, 1, np.nan, np.nan],
              [22, 1, 1, 4, 4],
              [4, 2, 3, 3, 4],
              [1, 1, 4, 1, 5],
              [2, 4, 5, 2, 1]],

         [[17, 7, 10, 6, np.nan],
          [np.nan, 7, 8, 6, 9],
          [6, 10, 9, 8, 10],
          [6, 8, 7, 10, 8],
          [10, 9, 9, 10, 8]],

         [[16, 7, 10, np.nan, np.nan],
          [19, 19, 8, 6, 9],
          [6, 10, 9, 8, 10],
          [6, 8, 7, 10, 8],
          [10, 9, 9, 10, 8]],

         [[61, 7, 10, 6, np.nan],
          [19, 21, 8, 6, 9],
          [6, 10, 9, 8, 10],
          [6, 8, 7, 10, 8],
          [10, 9, 9, 10, 8]],

        [[51, 7, 10, 6, np.nan],
          [19, 21, 8, 6, 9],
          [6, 10, 9, 8, 10],
          [6, 8, 7, 10, 8],
          [10, 9, 9, 10, 8]],

        [[34, 7, 10, 6, np.nan],
          [19, 21, 8, 6, 9],
          [6, 10, 9, 8, 10],
          [6, 8, 7, 10, 8],
          [10, 9, 9, 10, 8]],

         [[12, 14, 12, 15, np.nan],
          [19, 11, 14, 14, 11],
          [13, 13, 16, 15, 11],
          [14, 15, 14, 16, 14],
          [13, 15, 11, 11, 14]]])

data = data.reshape(7,25)
minima = data[signal.argrelmin(data,axis=0,order=1)]
print minima
```

But it produced only one result which is same as:

```
test = np.array([13,17,16,61,51,34,12])
print test[signal.argrelmin(test)]
```

So above method could produce result for only the first element for each column.
How can I get result for other 24 elements?

Comment: What is `vvv`? Wouldn't you prefer adding this to your other question? They seem to be very strongly related.

Comment: @eickenberg I hope you can solve this question...

Answer (score 1):

Your problem here is almost exactly as I described in [my answer to your previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23500967/2457474). The issue is that there are NO other relative minima along axis 0 in your data array. You are already receiving the correct output from the function.

For example, in the second column:

2, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 14

There is NO relative minima as argrelmin understands it. If you would like for 2 to be a relative min, you can add the mode='wrap' argument to the function call. However, be careful of NaNs (again, see my answer to your original question).

Comment: Thank you very much. I could understand it. Up voted. Before accepting, could you please show me how to separate the retrieved minima values for each column? I mean how to group the column name(say 0;1;2;3;4) and retrieved minima(say 25; ; ; ;5,7)?

Comment: I would suggest taking a look at list comprehension. Something like `col_minima = [signal.argrelmin(row) for row in data.T]` (where a row in data.T is a column in data). I think that should give you the row positions of any minima present in the respective column. Unfortunately, I'm not currently able to test it.